# render a HTML canvas inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to solve a complex situation, where i already have a `Canvas element` rendered with some kind of text lines and etc. I don't know how and which way it was rendered. But now i need to set the transformation of that means rotate , scale it etc.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("item1-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var angle1 = 0.1;
var angle2 = 0.14;
var cs = Math.cos(angle1), sn = Math.sin(angle1);
var h = Math.cos(angle2);

var a = 100*cs, b = -100*sn, c = 200;
var d = h*100*sn, e = h*100*cs, f = 200;

ctx.setTransform(a, d, b, e, c, f);
```

As i set transform or any thing the canvas cleared and needed to be redrawn, but i don't know the exact mechanism of first drawing. To solve this i came to a thought to render a canvas inside another canvas, so that initial canvas don't need to be rendered any way. And we can set the transforms of second canvas.

How can i do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you render one (bitmap) canvas to another (using [`drawImage()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage)) just to introduce transformation you will get poor results. This is because the results of a canvas are not vectors, but pixels.

You need to trap and record the drawing commands on the first canvas context so that you can replay them later under a transformed context.

Comment: I get the first canvas by a library http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ so why i don't exactly know how it is rendered and don't want to dig it out. as you said of `drawImage` can you give me any example of it?

Comment: I have linked to the specs for drawImage().

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you also suggest me some transformation which would skew and tilt the image.

Comment: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#transformations